# How to ask DefaultAzureCredential to use my user credential locally

Tags: azure

I'm trying to develop a web app on an Azure VM that uses Azure Key Vault. Later this app will also be deployed to Azure. As far as I know, the most straight forward way to make the app work, both locally and deployed, with the key vault, is to use the `DefaultAzureCredential` class. The code would be like this:

```cs
string kvUri = "https://" + keyvaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
SecretClient client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
```

At runtime, the provider will [try different credential types in order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet).

This sounds exactly what I want:

- When developing locally (on the Azure VM, though), I want to use my user credential (user identity added to the key vault's permission) without any configuration, since I have already logged into the Visual Studio using the same user credential.
- Once deployed to Azure, I want to use the app registration credential (also added to the key vault's permission).

But when running the app locally, I'm getting a 403 error `The user, group or application .... does not have secrets get permission on key vault ...`

After looking up the object id in the error message, I realize it's the dev machine Azure VM's credential that the application uses, not my user credential.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Your dev machine is an Azure VM where you have installed Visual Studio and you have signed in using your credentials in Visual Studio. Is this correct? Also, have you assigned any managed identity to the VM?

Comment: @GauravMantri both yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the Azure VM from getting a token, you can exclude the `ManagedIdentityCredential` in your `Development` environment and only enable it in a Non-`Development` environment.

```cs
        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true
            });
        }
```

> Once deployed to Azure, I want to use the app registration credential (also added to the key vault's permission).

An Azure App Service can use a managed identity as well. There is no need for a separate App Registration.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#key-concepts for more information.

Comment: Should I understand the issue and your solution in this way: both my user account and my vm are enabled as identity, and there's no way to specify the order of the identity the default credential provider chooses. In my case, it's using the vm's identity (not user), which is something I don't want to add to the kv's permission. So the only option is to just exclude all the managed identity credential locally?

Comment: The internal order is EnvironmentCredential -> ManagedIdentityCredential -> ...-> VisualStudioCredential and cannot be changed. So your best bet is to exclude it completly from the token credential chain. The DefaultCredentialFactory will use a token from the first working TokenCredential, basically try-error-next.

Answer (score 0):

Create and identity if you wish to use (default identity)
appservice -> select you application -> identity->enable it ->should give you a Id
and than add it to key Vault Access policy
alternatively app registration can be used with tenantId,clientId,secret to connect to keyvault